# STM32 RTOS2 execuation code failed, it doesn't execute the thread properly

Tags: stm32, rtos

Here is my first RTOS2 under CMSIS library code. I need to know why it doesn't change the states of my LED.

```c
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * CMSIS-RTOS 'main' function template
 *---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stm32f10x_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f10x_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f10x_usart.h"
#include "RTE_Components.h"
#include "cmsis_os2.h"
#include "rtx_os.h"
#include "rl_net.h"
#include "cmsis_os.h" 

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Application main thread
 *---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

char i;

 void CLOCK(void){
    RCC_HSEConfig(RCC_HSE_ON);
    while(RCC_WaitForHSEStartUp()==ERROR);

    RCC_PREDIV2Config(RCC_PREDIV2_Div5);
    RCC_PLL2Config(RCC_PLL2Mul_8);
    RCC_PLL2Cmd(ENABLE);

    while(RCC_GetFlagStatus( RCC_FLAG_PLL2RDY)!=SET);

    RCC_PREDIV1Config(RCC_PREDIV1_Source_PLL2,RCC_PREDIV1_Div5);    
    RCC_PLLConfig(RCC_PLLSource_PREDIV1,RCC_PLLMul_9);
    RCC_PLLCmd(ENABLE);

    while(RCC_GetFlagStatus( RCC_FLAG_PLLRDY)!=SET);

    RCC_SYSCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLKSource_PLLCLK);

    RCC_HCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLK_Div1);
    RCC_PCLK1Config(RCC_HCLK_Div2);
    RCC_PCLK2Config(RCC_HCLK_Div1);

    while (RCC_GetSYSCLKSource() != 0x08);


}

__NO_RETURN void app_main (void *argument) {

//  osThreadTerminate(osThreadGetId());



    while(1) {
        if(i==0) {
            GPIO_SetBits(GPIOA,GPIO_Pin_4);
            i=1;
        } else {
            GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA,GPIO_Pin_4);
            i=0;
        }   
    }
}


int main (void) {

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIOStruc={0};
    CLOCK();

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA,ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_AFIO,ENABLE);//Map

    GPIOStruc.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
    GPIOStruc.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_4;
    GPIOStruc.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA,&GPIOStruc);


    osKernelInitialize();                 // Initialize CMSIS-RTOS
    osThreadNew(app_main, NULL, NULL);    // Create application main thread
    osKernelStart();                      // Start thread execution

    while(1){}

}
```

In addition, I need to know:

1. app_main runs repeatedly? it means if I use "   netInitialize ();"
   function right after "app_main" it repeats it many times or it just got stuck in "while(1){" loop?
2. how a thread can be run after a specific time ( for example each 500us)?

Comment: Can you explain what you think the line: `osThreadTerminate(osThreadGetId());` does?

Comment: Sorry. I have forgotten to mention I have commented this line "// osThreadTerminate(osThreadGetId());" but in the main post I forgot to say.

Comment: Ok - so if you're not terminating your `app_main` thread immediately, then you should have your LED on the A4 pin blinking so fast that you can't see it blink. If you use an oscilloscope you'd see a square wave.

Comment: What do you mean by _right after "app_main"_? There is no "after" for `app_main` - it's a while(1) loop so it'll run forever.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Answer (score 4):

The thread calls to terminate itself right before it would begin to flash the LEDs. The debugger exists to find these kind of issues.

Comment: yes Thread is terminated before doing led blink task.